# テキストファイルの中に記述されている１行目を取得し、画面に表示したい

Tags: php

- wordで`1行目,2行目,3行目, ...`と文字を入力してテキストファイル(`phptanaka.txt`)を作成
- viエディタで下記コードを入力してphpファイル(`aaa.php`)を作成

ターミナルで`php aaa.php`と実行するとエラーは出ませんが`?P?s??`と文字化けして表示されてしまいます。
あともう少しのところまで来ているような気がするのですが、時間だけが経過してしまいます。
どなたかご助言下れば幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

```
<?php

$fp= fopen("/Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/phptanaka.txt","r");

$line = fgets($fp);

fclose($fp);

$hoge = file("/Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/phptanaka.txt");

print $hoge[0];

?>
```

Comment: `$line`を`print`すればいいのでは？ちなみに入力された文字列と文字コードは？あと環境も記載すると良いです。

Comment: プログラムを作成する際にWordの使用はおすすめしません。viエディタが使用できるなら、対象のテキストファイルもviで作成する方が余計なトラブルを避けられます。

Comment: テキストファイルをviエディタで作成したら表示されました

Comment: 助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/135352

Comment: @アフロ もし解決した場合は解決した内容を自己回答するか、参考になったコメント主に回答を依頼し承認するかしてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

文字に？が出ているということは、UTF8の文字をShift-Jisで表現しようとして文字化けしたのかと思います。
コンソールの文字コードを確認してみて、Shit-Jisになっていれば、UTF8にしてみてはどうでしょうか？

http://okguide.okwave.jp/guides/590

以下参考URLからの引用です(半角の#をつけるとBoldになるので、全角にしています)

> - 現在の文字コード確認 
>     ＃ echo $LANG
> - 文字コード変更 
>     ＃ LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8

Comment: echo $LANGで確認するとUTF-8でした。

Comment: more コマンドでphptanaka.txtファイルの中身を見てみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: /Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/phptanaka.txt "はバイナリファイルである可能性があります。と表示されました

Comment: phptanaka.txtはWordで作られたとありますが、テキストファイルとして書き出しましたか？拡張子を変えただけですか？

Answer (score 1):

テキストデータを作成する際は文字コードを気にした方がいいかと思います。
対処方法としては、
１．Webサーバ内で作成する(vimなど)
　　Webサーバに設定していなければ普通サーバのデフォルト文字コードが使われるので、
　　同一サーバ内で作成したテキストファイルは同じ文字コードで表示されるはずです。
２．作成した環境の文字コードからWebサーバ環境の文字コードに変換する。
　　Windowsでテキストデータを作成した場合、大抵ShiftJISです。

```
<?php
$path="/Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/phptanaka.txt";
$fp= fopen($path,"r");
$line = fgets($fp);
fclose($fp);
//文字コードを変換して表示
print mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', 'sjis-win');
```

Answer (score 1):

プログラム(ソースコード)やプログラムで扱うテキストデータの作成にWordの使用はおすすめしません。
viエディタが使用できるなら、対象のテキストファイルもviで作成する方が余計なトラブルを避けられます。

Comment: @アフロ コメントからまとめた回答を勝手に作成しました。解決したのであれば、今後、同様の質問をする人が参照しやすくなるので、回答を「承認済み」にして質問をクローズしてください。

Comment: @tanalab2 ツリー上にいない人に対しては＠コメントはつかえなかったと思います。また、他の人のコメントを代理で投稿する場合は投稿前にコメントでコメント主に回答を促してください。反応がない場合は代理投稿し回答をコミュニティwikiに変換すると良いです。でないと人によっては「コメントで確認してたのに回答を取られた」となりかねないので…

Comment: @tanalab2 誰かのコメントを元に回答を行う際は`@名前`で記述しておくと、言及したユーザーにも信用度が少し入るはずなので参考までに。

Comment: @Myaku さん 申し訳ありませんでした。ルールを理解しておりませんでした。「承認済み」にならずに放置される質問が多いので、質問者に「承認済み」してくださいと呼びかけるつもりの行動でした。マナー違反でした反省いたします。

Comment: @cubick さん申し訳ありません。人の回答を横取りするような行動を取ってしまいました。反省いたします。